# model e controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

I've this this model City.php in app\Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    //
}
```

and this CityController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
      $cities = City::OrderBy('city_code')->get();
      return view('testcities',compact('cities'));
    }
```

but i get back this error in laravel:

> Error Class 'App\Models\City' not found

Comment: did you try "composer dump-autoload"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rename `cities.php` to `Cities.php`. But based on [Laravel best practices](https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/#models) Model names MUST be in singular form with its first letter in uppercase. So it's better to create model name with `City` rather than `Cities`.

Comment: hello Muhammad, i've created a new controller with first letter uppercase but error is the same. i've edited the post

Comment: check on *composer.json*, is this code exist? `"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },`

Comment: It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project, maybe your model was not generated in the list, but after dump-autoload it generated

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your class is named `Cities.php`. You can also try to run `composer dump-autoload` to tell Composer to read all your classes again.

Comment: is named cities.php with lowercase, is this the error?

Comment: Could be, try to rename it and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Mariano PSR-4 autoloading (which Laravel uses) is documented [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). The point 3.3 under specification does state the file name needs to match the case of the class name

Comment: https://pastebin.com/11TNExmB this is my dump-autoload

i've edited the post, and this is my autoload result